# end date should be five days greater then start date

Tags: c#

These are the variables I'm using:

```
var start = new DateTime();
var End = new DateTime();
```

Help me out by validating with if condition.

Comment: Do you mean *exactly* five days greater, or *at least* five days greater? What if they're out by a few milliseconds? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly you will have to try something like

```
if (start.AddDays(5) == End)
```

[DateTime.AddDays Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

Comment: Well... hopefully they're not off by a millisecond :-)  But yeah, works.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate a TimeSpan between the two dates and use properties of TimeSpan to determine how far apart they are, e.g.

```
TimeSpan diff = new TimeSpan(End.Ticks - start.Ticks);
double daysApart = diff.TotalDays;

if (daysApart >= 5.0) // Do stuff (assumes you want at least 5 days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TimeSpan elapsed;
elapsed = end.Subtract(start);
if (elapsed.Days > 5)
//Do stuff
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime

Answer (score 0):

```
if(end.Subtract(start).Days > 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should familiarize yourself with the [DateTime structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y). For this in particular the [AddDays method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays) or depending on how you end up doing things the [Subtract method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract).

```
// Setting end date to start date plus 5 days
var start = new DateTime(); 
var end = start.AddDays(5)

// Testing if end date is the same as start date plus 5 days
if (start.AddDays(5) == end)
{
    // It true!
}

/// or like so...
if (end.subtract(start).Days >= 5)
{
    // It true!
}
```